# Application.Goto Target Cell Not in View

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a simple Excel Macro which is triggered when a user clicks on a cell in a worksheet (worksheet1). Basically the macro takes the value of the cell which was clicked on and selects a target cell in a separate worksheet (worksheet2) that has the same value.

The problem is that about 20% of the time after being directed to worksheet2, the target cell is highlighted but is just out of view, i have to scroll down a couple of rows to see it. I want to be able to ensure that the target cell is always in view after the user is directed to it, but I am not sure how this can be achieved.

This is in Excel 2016.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
   If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
    If Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Dim c As Range
     Dim ans As String
     Dim Lastrow As Long

     ans = ActiveCell.Value
     Lastrow = Sheets("worksheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

     For Each c In Sheets("worksheet2").Range("A2:A" & Lastrow)
       If c.Value = ans Then Application.Goto Reference:=Sheets("worksheet2").Range(c.Address): Exit Sub     

       Next
    End If
   End If
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: `Goto` has an optional `Scroll` argument

Comment: FYI - `Sheets("worksheet2").Range(c.Address)` is the same as `c` - you start out with a range, get its Address, then convert that back to a range...

Comment: Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use find to find the selected item in sheet2 then just select the sheet and the found cell

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim s As Range
    If Target.Column = 1 Then

        Set s = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("B:B").Find(what:=Target, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If Not s Is Nothing Then
            Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate
            s.Select
        Else: MsgBox Target.Value & " is not found in sheet 2"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This code definitely works better than mine, thanks.